# Getting ArrayList.get() to return

Tags: java

I am currently trying to write a a simple function translating an integer, and vice versa, to a 3bit binary string with zero padding. To test the intToBinary method I created a simple loop adding the integers 1 to 5 and translating each number into a binary string, then combine those binary strings into a larger string.

```
  ArrayList cityList = new ArrayList();
  String gene = "";
  for(int i = 1; i<5;i++){
    cityList.add(i, i);
    gene += intToBinary(i);
    System.out.println(gene + "" + cityList.get(i));
  }
  System.out.println(gene);
```

When I tried running this small bit of code I get an error at `cityList.get(i)`
Shouldn't the `Object.get(i)` method returns a variable at index i?
I tried initializing another `int` by doing `int cityNum = (int)cityList.get(i)` but got an error saying an `Object` was found instead of an `int`.

The variable type used in the `Object.add(int index, Object)` is `int` so it the get method should return an `int` variable.

Comment: `Arraylist cityList = new ArrayList()` is bad syntax; you should use `ArrayList<Integer, Integer> cityList = new ArrayList<Integer, Integer>()` or similar.  As it stands, the type isn't obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I was learning from turtorialspoint and that was the syntax they used in the example.

Comment: What is the error you get at `cityList.get(i)` is this a compile error ? If so what is the text of the error?

Comment: How are you even adding to the list? Isn't `cityList.add(i, i);` failing when `i = 1`?

Comment: Ok so i figure out why I got the error, I forgot that ArrayList index starts at 0 and I requested at index 1 before it was created. Stupid mistake, Should have look closer at the error.

Comment: Now I got this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - wrong number of type arguments; required 1 . Can someone explain this error to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could do it with something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, 3); i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
    while (sb.length() < 3) {
        sb.insert(0, '0');
    }
    System.out.printf("%d = %s%n", i, sb.toString());
}
```

Output is

```
0 = 000
1 = 001
2 = 010
3 = 011
4 = 100
5 = 101
6 = 110
7 = 111
```

To go vice-versa you can use [`Integer.parseInt(String,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) like

```
int val = Integer.parseInt("001", 2); // <-- 1
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to do. I also needed to combine the binary string into one larger string and thought the best way of doing so would be through the use of ArrayList.